# ?: ternary operator with two declarations after

Tags: c#

Can I use a ternary operator when I have more than one operation to perform per case?

```
var replace = list[row][col + 1] == "P" ? list[row][col] = "P", list[row][col] 
= "P" : list[row][col + 1] = ".";
```

Comment: What happens if you try it? Hint: adding parentheses can keep things clearly separated

Comment: var replace = list[row][col + 1] == "P" ? (list[row][col] = "P", list[row][col+1] 
    = "." ): list[row][col + 1] = ".";

this error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between and 'string'

Comment: Try adding parentheses like this: `var replace = (...) ? (...) : (...);`

Comment: does not work again

Comment: @PetkovAlexander what is with the comma?  Thats not valid syntax.  You have included your code but its not super obvious what you are trying to accomplish.  What is `replace`?  What are you trying to do (in plain words)?

Comment: It makes no sense to use a conditional operator in this context.  Use an `if` statement when you want to perform one of two sequences of actions based on a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to write this code is:

```
if (list[row][col + 1] == "P")
{
    //multiple operations
}
else
{
    //multiple operations
}
```

The ternary operator is not mean to support operations. It supports choosing between two values. You really shouldn't be assigning anything after the `?` mark.

As it turns out the `=` operator not only assigns but also returns a value, so you *might* figure out some way to make it work that way, for example by initializing an array with several values that are the result of an assignment:

```
// If c is true, a will be set to "A" and b will b e set to "B"
var q = c ? new[]{ a = "A", b="B"} : new string[]{};
```

But this is not the way the `?:` operator is meant to be used and would be very confusing code.